# Why is my ext4 HDD silent on kernel 4.9 and noisy on 5.15 or later?

Tags: filesystems, ext4

I have a HDD that still runs on a Debian Stretch system with kernel 4.9. The HDD was also mkfs'ed on that kernel.
When I manually mount the HDD on it, there are a few short and almost inaudible access noises.

When I boot a Linux with kernel 5.15 or 6.2 and mount the HDD there, it gets very loud and noisy for about 8 seconds, seemingly caused by accesses all over the HDD, like some sort of intensive quick check.

What is the reason for this?
And if it's possible: can this be disabled or at least limited to every X startups without disadvantages?

Comment: fsck? Assuming Ubuntu; Try this: Boot into "recovery mode" in there run fsck (try menu option *and* from the root prompt) - does it make the same noise?

Comment: The strong noise happens for manual mounts on an Arch based Linux (system-rescue.org) and current Ubuntu versions. Mounts in Debian Stretch with kernel 4.9 are almost inaudible. I assume it has something to do with newer `e2fsprogs` versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of the Linux kernel will prefetch block bitmaps when the file system is mounted read/write.   This is done in the background at a lower priority, to prevent it from slowing down any foreground tasks.    The goal of this prefetching is to prevent synchronous writes --- for example, if you are running a database workload, or an NFS server, the fsync or the requirement for the file system write be persistent before it can be acknowledged to the NFS client --- from potentially take a long time, if the file system's free space is badly fragmented, when the file system is first mounted.

This tended to be a problem for penny-pinching users who would let the cloud's block device get to 99% full, and then grow it by a tiny amount of space --- say, 10GB, then wait until the block device got up to 99%, and then give it another 10GB, and so on.    Not only did this cause gradual performance decreases, but then after the VM was rebooted, and the file system was freshly rebooted, now the first time a synchronous block allocation is attempted, the block allocator might need to read in potentially thousands of block bitmaps to find a contiguous set of blocks for optimal data placement --- or compromise by using a bunch of singleton free 4k blocks, resulting in a very badly fragmented file.

To fix this, first, we try to get the message out that trying to save every last penny by waiting until the very last minute and then growing the block device by a really tiny amount is an amazingly stupid idea, since the few cents that you have in storage costs, is swamped by the CPU cost and reduced transactions per seconds.   Next we do background prefetching of the block bitmaps, and finally, if not all of the block bitmaps are read in by the time we need to do an allocation, we've adjusted the block allocator to try to be less perfectionistic in finding the best possible block allocation, and settle for a slightly more fragmented file as being preferable to a fsync taking multiple minutes (in some spectacularly pathological worst cases).

The block bitmap prefetching has pretty much no downside, and a lot of upside, so it's enabled by default.   But if those few seconds of disk activity is offensive to you, you can turn it off via the mount option no_prefetch_block_bitmaps.   (The mount option was primarily for debugging so we could do A/B experiments while the feature was being developed.)    I don't recommend turning it off, however.